# JQuery FullCalendar freezing after removing an event

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I am using [FullCalendar](http://fullcalendar.io/) with an array of events to populate it. To remove events from the calendar, the user clicks an event box and a dialog box pops up. There is an x in this box that triggers the removeEvent method.

In this method I filter out the event matching this id of the removed element, then remove and re-add the source like this

```
calendar.fullCalendar('removeEvents');
calendar.fullCalendar('removeEventSource', addedEvents);
calendar.fullCalendar('addEventSource', addedEvents);
calendar.fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
calendar.fullCalendar('rerenderEvents');
```

All of this works fine (the event gets removed), but after that, I can no longer interact with the events. Clicking an event does not open the dialog box. It's almost as if the elements are no longer there, but I can still see them.

Any help troubleshooting this would be appreciated. Thank you.